# Nothing inside the S3 API's getObject callback is running in Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I'm having a problem where I can't read my file from S3... or even get inside the S3 callback. I'm using node 8.10 for my lambda, and I've verified everything is running until I try to get inside of getObject -- the `console.log` below won't even run. Does anything look askew here? I've granted full access to lambda and S3, so I don't think that's the issue.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    const s3options = {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    }   

    const params = {
        Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
        Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key,
    }

    const s3 = new AWS.S3(s3options)    

    s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        // callback(null, data.Body.toString('utf-8'))

        console.log('I am here!')
    })

}
```

Comment: Async functions need to return a promise, do they not?  Lambda doesn't know you're not done.

Comment: Well, I feel like a tool. Deleted the "async" keyword and everything's fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trying to use *async/await* feature of Node v8.x, then you have to wrap your code into **try**/**catch** block and use a promise (I mean it's not necessary to wrap your function code, but you still have to implement try/catch block inside your app).

Note: AWS-SDK already promisified, means that **you don't have** to promisify AWS-SDK methods or use callbacks. Just simple append **.promise()** to your method as a tail, and add **await** keyword as a prefix to a method that is you trying to call.

Example:

Before:

```
s3.getObject(params, (err, data) => {
        // callback(null, data.Body.toString('utf-8'))
```

After:

```
try 
{
    const s3Response = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

    // if succeed 
    // handle response here
}
catch (ex) 
{
    // if failed
    // handle response here (obv: ex object)
    // you can simply use logging
    console.error(ex);
}
```

Then your code has to look like this:

```
// it's really cool to use ES6 syntax to import modules: import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
// btw, you don't have to import AWS-SDK inside the handler file

// const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

exports.handler = async (event) => {

    const s3options = 
    {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_KEY,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
        // do not forget include a region (e.g. { region: 'us-west-1' })
    }   

    const params = 
    {
        Bucket: event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name,
        Key: event.Records[0].s3.object.key,
    }

    const s3 = new AWS.S3(s3options)    

    try 
    {
        const s3Response = await s3.getObject(params).promise();

        // if succeed 
        // handle response here
    }
    catch (ex) 
    {
        // if failed
        // handle response here (obv: ex object)
        // you can simply use logging
        console.error(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how I ended up solving the problem. One I learned about the promise() method, I made tweaks like the ones above, and my async lambda is working great. Thank you!