# s3PutObject has stopped working all of a sudden from Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have this code in my Lambda function

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    const bucketName = "dhaval-upload";

    let data = {
        firstname: event.firstname,
        lastname: event.lastname,
        email: event.email,
        userAgent: event.userBrowser,
        userIP: event.userIP
    };

    let params = {
      Body: JSON.stringify(data),
      Bucket: bucketName, 
      Key: event.email
    };

    s3.putObject(params);

    callback(null, { message: event.email});
};
```

This returns the success callback but does not write the object in s3.

and this was working but now for some reason it does not.

Please Note :- I checked cloudwatch logs and could not find the reason for the issue from it.

Comment: Do do you confirm that the file is not being uploaded to S3?

Comment: Right, cuz you have to use callbacks / async with try / catch. Take a look at an async implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52825290/nothing-inside-the-s3-apis-getobject-callback-is-running-in-lambda-function/52844365#52844365

Comment: Is your S3 bucket public or private?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try it like this, you should use callbacks / async to your code

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    const bucketName = "dhaval-upload";

    let data = {
        firstname: event.firstname,
        lastname: event.lastname,
        email: event.email,
        userAgent: event.userBrowser,
        userIP: event.userIP
    };

    let params = {
      Body: JSON.stringify(data),
      Bucket: bucketName, 
      Key: event.email
    };

    // s3.putObject(params);

    // callback(null, { message: event.email});
    // === it works like this === 
    s3.putObject(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) callback(null, err);
        else callback(null, { message: event.email });
    });
};
```